# Error publishing .net maui android app - XA5300)

Tags: android, maui

I finished a .net maui android app, but now I can't publish it to build the abb package.

If deply to my test phone everything goes fine.

I'm using this command:

```
dotnet publish -f:net6.0-android -c:Release
```

My results:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\32.0.448\tools\Xamarin.Android.Tooling.targets(69,5): error XA5300: The Android SDK directory could not be found. Check that the Android SDK Manager in Visu
```

al Studio shows a valid installation. To use a custom SDK path for a command line build, set the 'AndroidSdkDirectory' MSBuild property to the custom path. [D:\Proyectos\Proyectos.Net\ParadigmaN!\ParadigmaN\Paradigma
N.Apps.ControlN\ParadigmaN.Apps.ControlN.csproj]

My SDK manager has my platform target as 31 as my app needed:

[image]

and My tools:

[image]

Whats wrong with my command?
How can I do to build my .abb android packages ?

Comment: Have you set Linking to None ?

Comment: Hi. sorry about my ignorance but what it means ?

Comment: You can check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/?tabs=windows#configure-the-linker)